# G Power Settings for Friedman Test Comparing Multiple Models

Tags: machine-learning, gpower

**UPdated to convey statistical question:**
The underlying statistical question is one of which test to use: I have three models against a single dataset. I want to see which model is better. Is repeated measures ANOVA the appropriate test, or regular one-way ANOVA?

Also, is my number of groups 1 since I'm just testing against model type (which has 3 levels representing each of the three models I'm comparing)? Near the end of this post I mention three as the number of my groups, but I think those are just the levels (three different model types)? I'm confused.

---

I'm trying to figure out how to configure GPower's settings for a Friedman's test comparing three machine learning models (RF, LR, and another form of LR).

I believe it is a between-factors repeated measures test, but I'm having trouble confirming the "Number of Groups" and "Number of Measurements." I think my "Number of Groups" is three representing the three models. What about "Number of Measurements"?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Thank you.  But to answer this question, we need to know what measurements of these models you are making, because the choice of test depends on the experimental design.

Comment: THank you - my measures are AUC and number of variables. So one continuous and another integer.

Comment: P.S.  The second paragraph of my post above asks a related question about number of groups.

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only as comments. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments can be deleted and are often seen only be a few

Comment: This has been done.